# Efficient way to show data in wpf datagrid?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, optimization, datagrid

I have a a million objects in a list, the object contains multiple string and therefore memory usage is almost double. As strings in c# take 26 + (length * 2) bytes of memory.

As i want to display huge data sets, memory is a problem. i thought of to store string as null terminated char arrays and convert them to string at render time of datagrid rows, but cant find a way to change data at render time.

is there any way i can achieve that?
or any other solution?

Comment: there is not a single list, multiple data lists can be created so that data can be compared visually in diffrent datagrid windows.

Comment: what are you doing to your poor users giving them a list with a million items in it.

Comment: window congaing disassembly of a binary which is interactive and can jump from one end to another, nm, it is not as you are thinking, its a requirement.

Comment: Why do you need to display million objects in a list? Did you consider some pagination to limit max number of data that can be displayed at one time? You can convert data at render time pretty easily if you use MVVM and your list has enabled UI virtualization - if so the getter for data on your ViewModel will be called only when the object will be rendered (visibled/scrolled on UI).

Comment: i cannot use pagination. list has enabled ui virtualization, but data in memory reaches 3-4gb and also need memory to process data. emulation decompilationd and all

Comment: So what is exactly the reason you need to show million of items when the user can see just a tiny part of it?

Comment: because the data shows the disassembly of a section of a exe file, and while emulating that can jump to any part of that list

Comment: Well you can try to create strings from char array when the item is rendered using ui virtualization as i said previously.

Comment: rhats what i am asking, how to do that!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189168/discussion-between-alok-saini-and-lukas-koten).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem using data virtualization, as there is no way you can reduce memory usage of string, list or object classes.

i used this grid, works with .net 4.7, dont know if works with below versions.

> https://github.com/FormatD/FastWpfGrid

And used a database at backend.